# Как вставить элемент в массив

Tags: php

Если у меня отсутствует весь элемент массива $array["Department"]="какая-нибудь строка..." Подскажите, как мне вставить элемент с этим названием и пустым значением в массив. И как вставить сразу проверку условием, если элемент массива отсутствует, то добавить элемент Department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно через функцию [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) проверять:

```
if (!array_key_exists('Department', $array)) {
    $array['Department'] = null;
}
```